# Fortran 90: Value of a variable changes seemingly at random. Memory allocation?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I was trying to find a bug in a larger code and isolated the problem to the following code snippet which I put into a separate program for troubleshooting. Why on earth does one entry (and only one) of the matrix "Ga" change by initializing HEB with zeros? If I remove this initialization, both "Ga" outputs will be the same. Please scroll down to the bottom to see where the problem shows. Thank you so much, this is driving me nuts. I use ifort for compilation.

```
program AC
 implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
  integer :: n, ndim, k, j, i, l, m, o, steps
  real(dp) :: emax, omega, pi, EFermi, auev
  complex(dp) :: Grs,Gas, ACCond, tinyc, cunit, czero, cone

  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaL(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaL_EB(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Gr(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Ga(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GrInv(:,:)    
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GaInv(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GrDiag(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GaDiag(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GrInvDiag(:,:)   
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GaInvDiag(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaR(:,:)    
  complex(dp), allocatable :: GammaR_EB(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: R(:,:) 
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Yc(:,:)         
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Yd(:,:)        
  complex(dp), allocatable :: AnaInt(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: H(:,:)         
  complex(dp), allocatable :: HEB(:,:)          
  complex(dp), allocatable :: HamEff(:,:)    
  complex(dp), allocatable :: EigVec(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: InvEigVec(:,:)  
  complex(dp), allocatable :: EigVal(:)       
  complex(dp), allocatable :: ctemp(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: S(:,:)          
  complex(dp), allocatable :: SelfL(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: SelfR(:,:)      
  complex(dp), allocatable :: SHalf(:,:)     
  complex(dp), allocatable :: InvSHalf(:,:)   
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Abba(:,:)   
  complex(dp), allocatable :: Integrand(:,:)
  complex(dp), allocatable :: HDiag(:,:)
  complex(dp), allocatable :: unity(:,:)

!Lapack arrays and variables
  integer :: info, lwork
  complex(dp), allocatable :: work(:)       
  real(dp), allocatable :: rwork(:)    
  integer,allocatable :: ipiv(:)

!########################################################################

!Constants
    pi = 3.14159265359
    cunit = (0,1)
    czero = (0,0)
    cone = (1,0)
    tinyc = (0.0, 0.000000000001)


!System and calculation parameters
    ndim = 3 !Dimension of the Hamiltonian
    lwork = ndim*ndim
    EFermi = 0.0 
    emax = 5.0 !Energy in eV to which the admittance is to be calculated
    steps = 1000 !Number of energy steps for the admittance calculation


    allocate(Integrand(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(H(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Yc(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Yd(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(S(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(SelfL(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(SelfR(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(HamEff(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaR(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaL(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(AnaInt(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(EigVec(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(EigVal(ndim))
    allocate(InvEigVec(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(R(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaL_EB(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GammaR_EB(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(HEB(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Ga(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Gr(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GaInv(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GrInv(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GaDiag(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GrDiag(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GaInvDiag(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(GrInvDiag(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(Abba(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(HDiag(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(unity(ndim,ndim))


!################################################


!Definition of the trial system

    H = reshape((/ -0.3, -0.8, -0.2, -0.8, -0.5, -0.14, -0.2, -0.14, -0.24 /), shape(H))
    SelfL = reshape((/ -0.1*cunit, -0.3*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.3*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit /), shape(SelfL))
    SelfR = reshape((/ -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.6*cunit, -0.0*cunit, -0.6*cunit, -0.3*cunit /), shape(SelfR))

    HamEff(:,:)=(H(:,:) + SelfL(:,:) + SelfR(:,:))   
    GammaL(:,:)=(-2.0 * cmplx(aimag(SelfL(:,:)),0.0_dp,dp)) 
    GammaR(:,:)=(-2.0 * cmplx(aimag(SelfR(:,:)),0.0_dp,dp))

unity(:,:) = 0.0_dp
do i=1,ndim
unity(i,i) = cone
end do



!Calculate Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian (Checked! Yields correct Eigenvalues for trial matrix).
!In the PDF: B = EigVec, B^(-1) = InvEigVec, Hk = EigVal

    allocate(ctemp(ndim,ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork),rwork(2*ndim))
    ctemp(:,:) = HamEff(:,:)
    call zgeev('N', 'V', ndim, ctemp, ndim, EigVal, InvEigVec, ndim, EigVec, ndim, work, lwork, rwork, info)
    deallocate(work,rwork)
    deallocate(ctemp) 

    InvEigVec(:,:)=EigVec(:,:)
    lwork = 3*ndim
    allocate(ipiv(ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork))
    call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,InvEigVec,ndim,ipiv,info)
    call zgetri(ndim,InvEigVec,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(ipiv)


!Green Function at E=2
    GrInv(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    GaInv(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    Gr(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    Ga(i,j) = 0.0_dp

    do i=1,ndim
       do j=1,ndim
          GrInv(i,j) = (3.0_dp + tinyc)*unity(i,j) - HamEff(i,j)
       end do
    end do

    do i=1,ndim
       do j=1,ndim
          GaInv(i,j) = (3.0_dp - tinyc)*unity(i,j) - conjg(HamEff(j,i))
       end do
    end do


!Matrix Inversions

    Ga(:,:)=GaInv(:,:)
    lwork = 3*ndim
    allocate(ipiv(ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork))
    call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,Ga,ndim,ipiv,info)
    call zgetri(ndim,Ga,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(ipiv)

    Gr(:,:)=GrInv(:,:)
    lwork = 3*ndim
    allocate(ipiv(ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork))
    call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,Gr,ndim,ipiv,info)
    call zgetri(ndim,Gr,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(ipiv)




    GrInvDiag(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    GaInvDiag(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    GrDiag(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    GaDiag(i,j) = 0.0_dp
    do i=1,ndim
       do j=1,ndim
          GrInvDiag(i,j) = (3.0_dp + tinyc)*unity(i,j) - HDiag(i,j)
       end do
    end do

    do i=1,ndim
       do j=1,ndim
          GaInvDiag(i,j) = (3.0_dp - tinyc)*unity(i,j) - conjg(HDiag(j,i))
       end do
    end do



!Matrix Inversions

    GaDiag(:,:)=GaInvDiag(:,:)
    lwork = 3*ndim
    allocate(ipiv(ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork))
    call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,GaDiag,ndim,ipiv,info)
    call zgetri(ndim,GaDiag,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(ipiv)

    GrDiag(:,:)=GrInvDiag(:,:)
    lwork = 3*ndim
    allocate(ipiv(ndim))
    allocate(work(lwork))
    call zgetrf(ndim,ndim,GrDiag,ndim,ipiv,info)
    call zgetri(ndim,GrDiag,ndim,ipiv,work,lwork,info)
    deallocate(work)
    deallocate(ipiv)



!The problem occurs here. Why does an entry of Ga get deleted by initialization of a new array HEB?

    write(*,*) Ga
    write(*,*) "--------------------"


     HEB(i,j) = 0.0_dp


    write(*,*) Ga




!#############################################

    deallocate(Integrand)
    deallocate(HEB)
    deallocate(Yc)
    deallocate(Yd)
    deallocate(HamEff)
    deallocate(GammaR)
    deallocate(GammaL)
    deallocate(Ga)
    deallocate(Gr)
    deallocate(GaInv)
    deallocate(GrInv)
    deallocate(GaDiag)
    deallocate(GrDiag)
    deallocate(GaInvDiag)
    deallocate(GrInvDiag)
    deallocate(AnaInt)
    deallocate(EigVec)
    deallocate(EigVal)
    deallocate(InvEigVec)
    deallocate(H)
    deallocate(S)
    deallocate(SelfL)
    deallocate(SelfR)
    deallocate(R)
    deallocate(GammaL_EB)
    deallocate(GammaR_EB)
    deallocate(Abba)
    deallocate(HDiag)
    deallocate(unity)
end program AC
```

Comment: when you write GrInv(i,j) = 0.0_dp etc, outside any "do", what the values of i and j is supposed to be? I.e., it seems to be there's some usage of var which do not hold correct values, in particular you used i in a previous do-loop to initialize unity - likely you stripped too much, injecting apparent errors?

Comment: Yes that is something i must have overlooked. I corrected all occurences to an initialization of type "GaDiag(:,:) = 0.0_dp" and the problem still occurs. EDIT: nevermind! I forgot HEB(i,j) itself! Thanks, that's already it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ShinTakezou points out, you seem to have a problem in using `i` and `j` outside of a `DO` loop. Unless re-initialized, the variables used for a `DO` loop are 1 larger than their last value (that is, you will find `i=j=4` if you were to print it to screen). Apparently, the memory address `HEB(4,4)` lines up with the memory address for `GA(3,1)`.

The way to fix this is to either use `HEB=0._dp` or `HEB(:,:)=0._dp` and you will get the same answer before and after the print statement.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Are there any compilers or compiler settings that show mistakes like this? I spent days looking for this because I thought the error would be in the mathematics/physics of the code

Comment: @user464293 Of course. With ifort, you add `-check` to your compile options. It will still compile without fail, but it will give you a `Run-Time Check Failure` error. If you have `-g -traceback` included in your compiler flags, it will present the line number of the error (in your case, the first occurs at `GrInv(i,j) = 0.0_dp`).